# Как настроить location для отдачи статики при любом пути, кроме /api/

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, location

Не могу даже понять как сделать просто при любом.
Что то типо того,  location * {}

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     example.com;

    root /var/www/html;

    location /api/ {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }


    location  / {
      root /var/www/build;
    }

  }
```

В /var/www/build -  у меня лежит сборка SPA. (index.html, js/, css/)
И мне нужно, что бы я мог загружать SPA, не только заходя на example.com, но и при любом другом example.com/some-route

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Tue, 05 May 2020 18:08:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 2037
Last-Modified: Mon, 04 May 2020 20:42:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5eb07e23-7f5"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Length: 2037 (2.0K) [text/html]
Remote file exists and could contain further links,
but recursion is disabled -- not retrieving.
```

Comment: `location /api/ {...}; location / {...}`

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, поменял местами локейшены, как вы написали, но все равно, при   /<some-path> возвращается 404.

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста: [mcve]

Comment: Конфиг в студию. И что значит «отдачу статики по любому пути»?

Comment: Этот конфиг не работает или в чём проблема? Должен работать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, дополнил вопрос

Comment: @andreymal, он работает, но если обновить страницу с любым роутом кроме example.com, то 404.

Comment: 404 от кого? От api или от nginx? Если не от nginx, значит разбирайтесь с вашим api

Comment: значит, в каталоге `/var/www/build` находится файл `index.html`. и этот файл, как и полный путь к нему, читабелен для пользователя, от имени которого выполняется процесс nginx. а что вам тогда выдаёт `$ wget -S --spider http://example.com/index.html`? приложите полный вывод к тексту вопроса, пожалуйста.

Comment: @andreymal, 404 -   от nginx

Comment: Тогда в логе ошибок должно быть написано, что nginx попытался найти и почему не нашёл

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, приложил к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле вы хотите что бы любой неизвестный файл открывал `index.html`. На самом деле я рекомендую не делать этого для папок `/js` и `/css` (у вас же нет таких роутов?). В результате получится примерно так:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     example.com;

    # сразу указываем правильный root
    root /var/www/build;

    # /api/ проксируем
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    # если есть файл, то отдаём его, если нет, то отдаём /index.html
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # для папок /js/ и /css/ не отдаём /index.html, это обычно не имеет смысла.
    location /js/ {
        # default
    }

    location /css/ {
        # default
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Именно то, что нужно!)